# Parsing number with negative suffix

Tags: java, number-formatting, decimalformat

Can someone explain to me why the below code gives this output?

```
1.2
null
```

Running the following code:

```
String positive = "1.2+";
String negative = "1.2-";
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
format.setPositiveSuffix("+");
format.setNegativeSuffix("-");  
format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US));
System.out.println(format.parse(positive, new ParsePosition(0)));
System.out.println(format.parse(negative, new ParsePosition(0)));
```

This works though, but I do not like the repetition of the pattern:

```
String positive = "1.2+";
String negative = "1.2-";
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.0+;0.0-");  
format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.US));
System.out.println(format.parse(positive, new ParsePosition(0)));
System.out.println(format.parse(negative, new ParsePosition(0)));
```

Is the suffix not intended to be used for parsing?

Comment: parse is not guaranteed to consume the whole string. It will stop when it gets a character it doesn't know what to do with.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know, but I thought I told it what to do when I set the suffix? And why does it handles + but not -?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I would also assume that the second code is slower, as it would need to parse the whole string twice?

Comment: I have to admit, I have never seen suffixes used. Perhaps its behaviour isn't what you want.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Me neither. And googling for it yielded very little result. And the javadocs is useless to say the least. Thus my note in the end: is it not even used for parsing? Odd that I cannot find any documentation at all

Comment: For the record, setting a negative PREfix works correctly with your code.  I checked the API and it is near worthless.  I say either just use the negative prefix or go a different route.

Comment: @ConorSherman The problem is that I have no control over the input.

Comment: Could you strip off the last character from the input string, parse the remaining digits with something like `Integer.parseInt(input)`, and then multiply by -1 if the last character was a '-'?

Comment: @ConorSherman I could do that. But my second code that works is cleaner. My main question is why I get the results I get

Answer (score 2):

As specified in the javadoc :

> The negative subpattern is optional; if absent, then the positive subpattern prefixed with the localized minus sign ('-' in most locales)

In your exemple, the parser is waiting "-1.2-", so you have to add this line :

```
format.setNegativePrefix("");
```

Have a nice day !

Comment: Did you try that code? I tried it as well before posting, did not work tho