# How to parse a string number with negative sign at its back

Tags: java, parsing

We are consuming a service which returns a value as `20.000-`. The trailing `-` signifies negative number. This is their standard.

How can I parse this to double without doing a string manipulation. I am looking for much direct way of parsing it.

Comment: You do have to do some string manipuation here, you don't really have a choice... Also, even the dot here will be problematic (if this is a floating point number, the decimal separator varies according to your locale).

Comment: @Jafar Ali, `They` can code according to there standards, then why are you forced to use some generic available API to handle this.

Comment: The team is using some tool to develop and they are following that tools standard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299319/parsing-number-with-negative-suffix

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to manipulate the string so that you extract the negative sign first:

```
String number = "20.00-";
boolean negative = false;

if(number.substring(number.length() - 1).equals("-")) {
    number = number.substring(0, number.length() - 1);
    negative = true;
}

double parsedNumber = Double.parseDouble(number);

if(negative) {
    parsedNumber *= -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two things from this.

1. String manipulation will have to be done
2. Preserving the precision of the number, if you're number is like 0.00000 and you want to keep all the zeroes.

Having said that, give this a try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "20.123456-";

    // Determine if positive or negative
    boolean negative = data.charAt(data.length() - 1) == '-';
    double dblData = negative 
            ? Double.parseDouble(data.substring(0, data.length() - 1)) * -1
            : Double.parseDouble(data);

    // Determine precision
    long precision = 0;
    if (data.contains(".")) {
        String decimalPart = data.split("\\.")[1];
        // 0x30 and 0x39 are the hex values for characters 0 - 9
        precision = decimalPart.chars().filter(c -> 0x30 <= c && c <= 0x39).count();
    }
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat();
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits((int)precision);

    // Display results
    System.out.println(nf.format(dblData));
}
```

Results:

```
-20.123456
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in  many ways-

1.above process is also aplicable

2.

String s = "200.0-";

```
    String[] str = s.split("-");

    double data=Double.parseDouble(str[0]);

    data*=-1;
```

Comment: This does not work if you have a positive number: you always multiply with -1. A better generic solution should test the presence of the '-' character like done in Pherion's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution by using also the Apache Common library (NumberUtils, useful for nullity check).

```
private Double normalizeDouble(String s){
    double multiple = 1.0D;
    if( s != null && s.endsWith("-")){
        multiple = -1.0D;
        s = s.replace("-", "");
    }

    return NumberUtils.toDouble(s) * multiple;
}
```

It is also compatible if numbers in the String are prefixed by the - character (normal behavior).