# Is there a way for EditText in android to take minus value and convert it to double?

Tags: java, android

> I have an EditText with the type as numberDecimal|numberSigned. I convert this value to double,
> when I enter fractional numbers it works fine, but when I enter minus/negative numbers, it crashes.

```
   identity=(Button) findViewById(R.id.identification_color);
                if(free_height.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0){
                double  middleinner=305;
                double outer=370;
                double x1= new Double(free_height.getText().toString());

                if (x1==middleinner)
                {
                    identity.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0,128,0));

                } ....
```

> Error Log:

```
22021-05-06 11:49:17.059 12610-12610/com.example.springtester E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.springtester, PID: 12610
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at java.lang.Double.<init>(Double.java:608)
    at com.example.springtester.MainActivity$1.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:67)
    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:11662)
    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:14943)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1287)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:587)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:517)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:38)
    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:849)
    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:618)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:393)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:89)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8154)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Comment: what error you are getting in logs?

Comment: send your error logs

Comment: I have added my errors in question

Comment: You should use `Double.parseDouble(free_height.getText().toString())` instead of `new Double(free_height.getText().toString())`.

Comment: @UrbanR I tried this method, but it didn't work

Comment: @maja Based on your error you are trying to parse string "-" which is not a double, you should wrap the `Double.parseDouble(free_height.getText().toString())` inside of a try/catch to catch any exceptions when parsing the string

Comment: That is what i am doing now, but i am trying to figure out how to take the minus and convert numbers again to double. A double number can be signed, correct? that is what i am trying to do

Comment: @maja a double in Java is signed. So the value can be negative.

Answer (score 0):

> I found the solution in this question
>
> [How to parse a string number with negative sign at its back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537365/how-to-parse-a-string-number-with-negative-sign-at-its-back)

```
String number = "20.00-";
boolean negative = false;

if(number.substring(number.length() - 1).equals("-")) {
    number = number.substring(0, number.length() - 1);
    negative = true;
}

double parsedNumber = Double.parseDouble(number);

if(negative) {
    parsedNumber *= -1;
```